# Understanding model.similarity in word2vec

Tags: word2vec

Hello I am fairly new to word2vec, I wrote a small program to teach myself

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

sentence=[['Yellow','Banana'],['Red','Apple'],['Green','Tea']]
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentence, min_count=1,size=300,workers=4)
print(model.similarity('Yellow', 'Banana'))
```

The similarity came out to be:
-0.048776340629810115

My question is why not is the similarity between banana and yellow closer to 1 like .70 or something. What am I missing? Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word2Vec doesn't work well on toy-sized examples – it's the subtle push-and-pull of many varied examples of the same words that moves word-vectors to useful relative positions.

But also, especially, in your tiny tiny example, you've given the model 300-dimensional vectors to work with, and only a 6-word vocabulary. With so many parameters, and so little to learn, it can essentially 'memorize' the training task, quickly becoming nearly-perfect in its internal prediction goal – and further, it can do that in many, many alternate ways, that may not involve much change from the word-vectors random initialization. So it is never forced to move the vectors to a useful position that provides generalized info about the words.

You can sometimes get somewhat meaningful results from small datasets by shrinking the vectors, and thus the model's free parameters, and giving the model more training iterations. So you could try `size=2, iter=20`. But you'd still want more examples than just a few, and more than a single occurrence of each word. (Even in larger datasets, the vectors for words with just a small number of examples tend to be poor - hence the default `min_count=5`, which should be increased even higher in larger datasets.)

To really see word2vec in action, aim for a training corpus of millions of words.